# Pass a model class object from a Fragment to another Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have 2 activitys A1 and A2, A1 contains Fragments i need to pass a model class object from these fragments to Activity A2?

**VerbFragment**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), VerbDetailActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Eventbus should solve this for you.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents]